# Python wxTree saving the tree to file

Tags: python, tree, wxpython

My problem is that when i have a node in my tree it wont save the tree to file.

the code to save to file is:

```
def project_save(self):


    try:
        output = open(self.project_file, 'w+')
        output.write(self.tree.GetItemText(self.root) + '\n')
        count = self.tree.GetChildrenCount(self.root)
        iter = 0
        child = ''

        for i in range(count):
            if i == 0:
                child, cookie = self.tree.GetFirstChild(self.root)

            else:
                child, cookie = self.tree.GetNextChild(self.root, cookie)

            output.write(self.tree.GetItemText(child) + '\n')
        output.close()
        self.projectdirty = False

    except IOError:
        MsgDlg(self, 'There was an error saving the new project file.', 'Error!', wx.OK)
```

when my tree looks like:

```
root
 |
  ---item
 |
  ---item
```

it works just fine

but when my tree looks like:

```
root
|
  ---item
 |
  ---item
 |
  -node
    |
     ---item
    |
     ---item
```

It give me an error and my file ends up blank

> File "project_manager.py"
>
> output.write(self.tree.GetItemText(child) + '\n')
>
> File "C:\Python27\lib\sit-packages\wx-2-8-msw-ansi\wx\contrls.py",
>   line 5303, in GetItemText
>
> return *controls*.TreeCtrl_GetItemText(*args, **kwargs)
>
> wx._core.PyAssertionError: c++ assertion "item.IsOk()" failed at
>   ....\src\msw\treectrl.cpp(963) in wxTreeCtrl::GetItemText(): invalid
>   tree item

Answer (score 0):

A couple years ago, the PersistentControls module was released which should help you save and restore just about any widget in wxPython. See the following links:

- [Original announcement](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/wxpython-users/4yRpm-ogHzE) / description
- PersistenceManager [Documentation](http://xoomer.virgilio.it/infinity77/AGW_Docs/persist.persistencemanager.PersistenceManager.html)

Comment: It's not exactly what i am after as my program allows for opening of another file and it changes the tree defined by that file. It would really help if i could just get it to save to file if there is a node. Thanks for the reply :)